# MailJet api set HTML email text

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I am using MailJet API. I am able to send the plain text email via MailJet. I tried for sending HTML mail but for some reason its not working. Here is my code.

```
        include('Mail.php');

    $recipients = 'abc@gmail.com'; //CHANGE

    $headers['From']    = 'admin@abc.com'; //CHANGE
    $headers['To']      = 'abc@gmail.com'; //CHANGE
    $headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

    $body = 'Test message';

    // Define SMTP Parameters

    $params['host'] = 'in.mailjet.com';
    $params['port'] = '25';
    $params['auth'] = 'PLAIN';
    $params['username'] = 'xxxxxx'; //CHANGE
    $params['password'] = 'xxxxxx'; //CHANGE

    // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method

    $mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

    // Send the message

    $mail = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

This code works perfect for plain text.
I tried changing `$params['auth'] = 'PLAIN';` to `$params['auth'] = 'HTML';`  but didn't worked.

I have also tried

```
    $message = new Mail_mime();
    $html = "<p>Test message</p>";  
    $message->setHTMLBody($html);
    $body = $message->get();
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code.

```
        include('Mail.php');
    include_once("Mail/mime.php");

    $recipients = 'abc@gmail.com'; //CHANGE

    $headers['From']    = 'admin@abc.com'; //CHANGE
    $headers['To']      = 'abc@gmail.com'; //CHANGE
    $headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';
        $message = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
        $html = "<p>Test message</p>";
        $message->setHTMLBody($html);
        $body = $message->get();

    // Define SMTP Parameters

    $headers = $message->headers($headers);

    $params['host'] = 'in.mailjet.com';
    $params['port'] = '25';
    $params['auth'] = TRUE;
    $params['isHTML'] = TRUE;
    $params['username'] = 'xxxxxxx'; //CHANGE
    $params['password'] = 'xxxxxxx'; //CHANGE

    // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method

    $mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

    // Send the message

    $mail = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```